# Datatables buttons not showing for Bootstrap example

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Any idea why the buttons (csv, excel, pdf, print etc) are not showing when using this code for bootstrap?

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html

I have this for styles:

```
<link href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This for scripts:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
```

And this JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var table = $('#reminders').DataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [[50, 100, 1000, -1], [50, 100, 1000, "All"]],
    "initComplete": function(){ 
      $("#reminders").show(); 
    },
    buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'colvis']
  });
  table.buttons().container().appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)' );
});
```

But the buttons are not showing... If I uncomment the dom and use Blfrtip the buttons do show, but I am curious as why the method in the example (without dom) isn't working...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Using [`dom`](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/#dom-parameter) parameter**

```
"dom": 'Blfrtip'
```

- `B` - Buttons
- `l` - length changing input control
- `f` - filtering input
- `r` - processing display element
- `t` - The table
- `i` - Table information summary
- `p` - pagination control

**Direct insertion**

The selector would be `#reminders_wrapper` or

```
table.buttons().container()
    .appendTo( $('.col-md-6:eq(0)', table.table().container()) );
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#reminders').DataTable({
    //"dom": 'Blfrtip',
    "lengthMenu": [
      [50, 100, 1000, -1],
      [50, 100, 1000, "All"]
    ],
    "initComplete": function() {
      $("#reminders").show();
    },
    "buttons": ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'colvis']
  });
  table.buttons().container().appendTo('#reminders_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
});
```

```html
<link href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>

<table id="reminders" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Unity Butler</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/12/09</td>
      <td>$85,675</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/12/16</td>
      <td>$164,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
      <td>Secretary</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2010/02/12</td>
      <td>$109,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2010/01/04</td>
      <td>$125,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>2012/06/01</td>
      <td>$115,000</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Like I said, It works if I add the "dom": 'Blfrtip' and the buttons display, but I am interested in why this method without it (like in the example on their site as well - without dom) isn't working. Can you get it to work without it, like in the example on the site?

Answer (score 7):

I just checked, and the DOM for the wrapper is not ready yet right after the `DataTable()` call. I'm using AJAX to get the data. But adding the call in the `initComplete` property worked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#reminders').DataTable({
    //"dom": 'Blfrtip',
    "lengthMenu": [
      [50, 100, 1000, -1],
      [50, 100, 1000, "All"]
    ],
    "initComplete": function() {
        table.buttons().container().appendTo('#reminders_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
        $("#reminders").show();
    },
    "buttons": ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'colvis']
    // Rest of configuration.
  });
});
```

Comment: Am having same issue in .net application my butons refuse to show at all even with the dom i have my correct referensces did this work for u in end

Comment: Yes, this worked. If you're calling table.buttons() right after calling DataTable(), try putting it inside initComplete.

Comment: Thx. I was having the same issue in Laravel. For some reason sometimes the buttons weren't appearing (mainly on new screens). It was fixed after we put them in the InitComplete.

Answer (score 2):

The `dom` option isn't just a set of flags to turn on/off features in datatables. It's also the html templates to use to render the those features. datatables-bootstrap-4.js overrides the default `dom` option to include some wrappers (but doesn't add the buttons as you found out). By setting `dom` to `Blrtip` you are wiping out the bootstrap templates. That's why it looks fine without the `dom` option (but no buttons) and setting the `dom` option to `Blrtip` gives you buttons but the wrappers go away. Instead of leaving out the `dom` option and inserting the buttons later (which works fine I suppose), you can also set `dom` to a modified version of the template datatables-bootstrap-4 uses, including the B option for buttons.

bootstrap-datatables-4.js sets this:

```js
'dom' : "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-6'l><'col-sm-12 col-md-6'f>><'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>"
```

So you can modify that to add the B flag like this:

```js
'dom' : "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-6'Bl><'col-sm-12 col-md-6'f>><'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>"
```